# What are the .awk files used for in /usr/share/awk directory?

Tags: awk

I'm using CentOS 7 system. I find below files under /usr/share/awk directory. What are those files used for?

```
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  382 Jun 28  2017 assert.awk
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  327 Jun 28  2017 bits2str.awk
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  307 Jun 28  2017 cliff_rand.awk
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  233 Jun 28  2017 ctime.awk
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  317 Jun 28  2017 ftrans.awk
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 2237 Jun 28  2017 getopt.awk
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 2491 Jun 28  2017 gettime.awk
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 1792 Jun 28  2017 group.awk
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  378 Jun 28  2017 join.awk
...
```

Comment: There is a reference to `/usr/local/share/awk`  in the [man-pages](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#:~:text=for%20AWKPATH%20is%20%E2%80%98.%3A/-,usr/local/share/awk,-%E2%80%99.14%20Since%20.%20is) which might give a hint to those files...

Answer (score 4):

Those are, I think, GNU awk specific. Those are files you can include into your code.

For example, `ctime.awk` provides a `ctime` function:

```sh
$ gawk -i ctime 'BEGIN {print ctime(1234)}'
Wed Dec 31 19:20:34 EST 1969
```

or

```sh
gawk '
  @include "ctime"
  BEGIN {print ctime(1234)}
'
```

See [Include Files](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Include-Files.html)
and [Extension Samples](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Extension-Samples.html)